# Unable to get the correct `rootPath` from Sitecore.Context.Site

Tags: configuration, site-configuration

In my code, I'm trying to access the root path for the current site.

Let's say I'm accessing my website `http://mywebsite`.

Here is the site definition:

```
<site
  patch:before="site[@name='website']"
  name="SomeSite"
  hostName="mywebsite"
  rootPath="/sitecore/content/Somesite"
  startItem="/home"
  database="master"
  loginPage="/login"
  ...
  />
```

When I try to get the root path, all methods I've tried return `/sitecore/content`. What I want to get is `/sitecore/content/Somesite`, which is what I've specified on the site definition.

I tried the following:

- `Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath`
- `foreach(var site in Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSiteInfoList())`
- `Sitecore.Context.Site.ContentStartPath` (which returns `null`)

Is there something I'm missing, like passing the current hostname or something that can pick the complete root path?

Comment: Hello Santosh. Your original question was hard to understand, so I edited it. I think it became much more readable, but please feel free to edit it again if you believe I misinterpreted something.

Comment: I have removed all of your comments and pasted the article links to your answer instead. I did that because the comments were not relevant for your question, they were logically part of the answer. I have additionally reformatted the answer to make it more readable and added a somewhat detailed description. This way, other users will be able to better understand what your code samples do. Please try to follow this format in the future when asking questions and posting answers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved the problem.

First, I created a helper method `GetSiteContext` that returns a `SiteContext` object based on a URL. This helper method iterates through all configured sites and tries to match them to the host name of the URL. If no site matches, the context of the `website` is returned.

```
public static SiteContext GetSiteContext(Uri requestUrl)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(requestUrl, "requestUrl");
    string requestHostName = requestUrl.Host;

    foreach (SiteInfo siteInfo in Factory.GetSiteInfoList())
    {
        if (IsMatch(requestHostName, siteInfo.HostName) || IsMatch(requestHostName, siteInfo.TargetHostName))
        {
            return new SiteContext(siteInfo);
        }
    }

    return SiteContext.GetSite("website");
}

private static bool IsMatch(string input, string wildcardPattern)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(wildcardPattern))
    {
        return false;
    }

    string regexPattern = WildcardToRegex(wildcardPattern);
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

You can see a usage example below. In this code, I am obtaining a site context based on the current request URL.

```
var siteContext = GetSiteContext(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
Item item;

if (siteContext != null)
{
     item = DatabaseProvider.MasterDatabase.GetItem(siteContext.RootPath + siteContext.StartItem);
}
```

Articles that helped me in resolving the issue:

- https://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/10/24/resolving-the-sitecontext-by-url/
- https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/sitecore-get-host-name-from-a-different-context/
- http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-context-site-resolution/
- https://soen.ghost.io/sitecore-sitecontext-and-contextdatabase-oh-my/
- https://ctor.io/correctly-switching-sitecore-contextes/

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. This is really helpful.